# C# switch case forcing

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Hi there I am making a C# windows forms app, I made a switch with all my teammates birthdays in order to calculate their birthday age, however I want to add the functionality that if today is their birthday a message appears.
Therefore I need something that goes into EACH CASE of the switch and there I will add a validation like if today's date is equal to bday, then messageshow "its name 1 birthday, today!"

```
switch (name)
{
    case "name 1":
        bday = DateTime.Parse("11.11.1988");
        break;
    case "name 2":
        bday = DateTime.Parse("11.12.1988");
        break;
    case "name 3":
        bday = DateTime.Parse("03.12.1987");  
        break;
}
```

Comment: what's hindering you from doing this?  also you would not need to do this in each case

Comment: I need that despite the NAME variable that the program goes into EACH CASE, I would say it would be like trying to make a SWITCH work as an IF, but I dont want to loose the SWITCH for the other uses.

Comment: You don't need it - you have a date in `bday` and the logic will be the same for every value of `bday` - you just compare it to today's date.  You can do it after the switch statement.

Comment: the problem is that the program fills the bday variable with one name, and I need to know if any of the other two have a birthday today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you use a Dictionary.
Dictionaries use other objects as Keys to retrieve their values.

In your case you could map all the birthdays to their names like:

```
Dictionary<string, DateTime> birthdays = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>;

//Add values like this 
birthdays.Add("name 1", DateTime.Parse("11.11.1988"));
birthdays.Add("name 2", DateTime.Parse("11.12.1988"));
...

//Then you could loop through all the entries
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, DateTime> entry in birthdays)
{
    if(entry.Value.Day == DateTime.Now.Day && entry.Value.Month == DateTime.Now.Month)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + " has birthday!");
    }
}
```

Comment: that's a good idea that I did not think of, one question though what would you add if user uses a different date format, Example:
dd.mm.yyyy
or 
mm.dd.yyyy
or
m.d.yyyy
or
d.m.yyyy?

Comment: Also about dictionary, how can I go into a direct entry later, for example if I want to search in the dictionary for a "name2", do I need to do a loop/foreach statement?

Comment: For that you could use DateTime.ParseExact("31.12.2014", "dd MM yyyy")  and so on. You dont have to loop through the dictionary to get a value from a key. You can use birthdays["name 1"] to retrieve the DateTime assigned to "name 1"

Comment: @dracebus, no you don't have to do a loop to find entries. birthdays["name 1"] will return "11.11.1988".

Comment: Definite +1 for guiding the OP away from `switch` and on to using `Dictionary`.

Comment: Sorry last comment, do you know why:  
Dictionary<string, DateTime> birthdays = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>;  
Compiler says:  
Error 1 A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type

Comment: `Dictionary<string, DateTime> birthdays = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();`  note the () at the end

Answer (score -1):

Based on what you provided in your snippet, you could do this sort of check outside of the case statement.  Example:

```
public void WhateverYourMethodIs()
{
    switch (name)
    {
        case "name 1":
            bday = DateTime.Parse("11.11.1988");
            break;
        case "name 2":
            bday = DateTime.Parse("11.12.1988");
            break;
        case "name 3":
            bday = DateTime.Parse("03.12.1987");  
            break;
    }   

    if (this.IsBirthday(bday))
    {
        // do whatever you want for when it's the name's birthday.
    }
}

public bool IsBirthday(DateTime bday)
{
    if (bday.Day == DateTime.Now.Day && bday.Month == DateTime.Now.Month)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

note the above would not take into account leap day birthdays.

Based on your comments, it sounds like you're hoping to evaluate the birthdays of all names regardless of the switch.  This won't work in your current approach.  `bday` is a single value that can only be attributed to the current "name".

***One*** way to accomplish what you're hoping for would be to use a class to represent a name as so:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    public bool IsBirthday
    {
        get
        {
            if (Birthday.Day == DateTime.Now.Day && Birthday.Month == DateTime.Now.Month)
                return true;

            return false;
        }        
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{    

    private List<User> Users = new List<User>();
    public void PopulateNames()
    {
        Users.Add(new User()
        {
            Name = "name 1",
            Birthday = DateTime.Parse("11.11.1988")
        };

        Users.Add(new User()
        {
            Name = "name 2",
            Birthday = DateTime.Parse("11.12.1988")
        };
        // etc
    }

    public void DoSomethingOnUsersWithABirthday()
    {
        foreach (User user in Users)
        {
            if (user.IsBirthday)
            {
                // do something for their birthday.
                Console.WriteLine(string.format("It's {0}'s birthday!", user.Name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the switch(name) is being filled by ONE value, and I need to chace all the dates inside the CASE.

Comment: "being filled by ONE value" - does not compute. can you try to elaborate?

Comment: before the switch the value of name is Environment.UserName
Therefore, I can only have one name at a time, I need to go into each case condition DESPITE the value of NAME.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, sometimes oneself is blind to the best solution and we just insist in doing it a certain way.